# Getting value in dropdownlist on DDL SelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to set a value in an object once a dropdownlist is changed, but I keep getting errors.

Basically all I'm trying to do is check if a value is selected, and change an object's variable when it does.

under

```
   protected void ddlPais_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

   Espectaculos.Pais = ddlPais.SelectedValue; //doesn't work.
```

Later on the idea is just making a button that calculates something based on .Pais and other factors.

It tells me an object reference is required for a non-static field. method or property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `PostBack` on the `DropDownList` otherwise `ddlPais_SelectedIndexChanged` won't get called.

**ASP markup:**(on the dropdown)

```
AutoPostBack="True"
```

**C#:**(in pageLoad)

```
ddlPais.AutoPostBack = true;
```